# Make nginx to use php7.2

Tags: php, nginx

I upgraded PHP from Version 7.0.27 to 7.2 on ubuntu16.04 with nginx.

[PHP 7.0 to PHP 7.2 - How to upgrade your server](https://jakelprice.com/article/php-70-to-php-72-how-to-upgrade-your-server)

When I run php -v on terminal, I can see:

```
PHP 7.2.2-3+ubuntu16.04.1+deb.sury.org+1 (cli) (built: Feb  6 2018 16:11:23) ( NTS )
Copyright (c) 1997-2018 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v3.2.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2018 Zend Technologies
with Zend OPcache v7.2.2-3+ubuntu16.04.1+deb.sury.org+1, Copyright (c) 1999-2018, by Zend Technologies
with Xdebug v2.6.0, Copyright (c) 2002-2018, by Derick Rethans
```

But when I see in browser echoing phpinfo(), it shows the older version of PHP like:

```
PHP Version 7.0.27-1+ubuntu16.04.1+deb.sury.org+1
```

That means nginx is not using PHP7.2
Where I need to configure for this.
Please, any help is appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: How did you install/upgrade to php 7.2?  What steps did you use to install?  What packages did you install?

Comment: Hi Thomas, I followed this steps: https://jakelprice.com/article/php-70-to-php-72-how-to-upgrade-your-server

Comment: And you installed `php7.2-fpm`, and updated your nginx configuration to use the socket or connection listener that 7.2 has instead of the one that `php7.0-fpm` provided (this is a *manual* step you have to do)?  What happens when you do `sudo apt-get remove php7.0-fpm`, does it give you a 502 error?

Comment: I updated "/etc/nginx/nginx.conf" file to "fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php7.2-fpm.sock;" . But I did not installed php7.2-fpm.

Comment: After installing php7.2-fpm and setting ""fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock;" to "fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php7.2-fpm.sock;"  on "/etc/nginx/nginx.conf" file it works. Thank you so much Thomas.

Comment: Glad to hear that worked.  I summarized the bits into an answer below.  Feel free to accept it at your convenience, to mark this question as solved/answered.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To augment Thomas' answer, this is the file you need to change:

```
sudo nano /etc/nginx/sites-available/default
```

or if you are running several sites on one nginx:

```
sudo nano /etc/nginx/sites-available/your_site_name
```

change this part in it

```
server {

    ...

    location ~ \.php$ {
        ...
        fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php7.2-fpm.sock;
    }

    ...
}
```

`php7.0-fpm.sock` to `php7.2-fpm.sock`

Comment: There is no file here, is this not a file? fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php7.2-fpm-sitename.sock;

Comment: the `default` or `your_site_name` in `/etc/nginx/sites-available` are the text files.

Comment: In my installation the default was `/var/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock` and I didn't realize I needed to remove `/var/` when upgrading to php7.2 and so it crashed my system. Took me forever, but this gist got me there: https://gist.github.com/GhazanfarMir/03bd1f1f770a3834d47274586d46ea62

Answer (score 3):

When you set up `php7.2-fpm`, you also have to adjust the NGINX configuration for where to actually point for where to route PHP requests.

In your `nginx`, you probably have `fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock;` for PHP 7.0.  You need to update this to be `fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php7.2-fpm.sock;`, and install `php7.2-fpm` as well.

And then restart `nginx` just in case to refresh the configs, and it should properly work with PHP 7.2.